# Filtering by a value in a list in a JSONB column

Tags: postgrest

I have a PostgreSQL table `table` with a column `column` containing JSONB data like this:

```
{
 "foo": "abc",
 "bar": "123",
 "baz": [
  "a=1",
  "a=2",
  "b=5",
  "c=1"
 ],
}
```

I set up PostgREST.

How can I filter for records that have the string `a=1` or the string `b=5` but not the string `c=1` in the `baz` array inside the JSONB column?

https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html#json-columns is very sparse on JSON columns.

I thought it was

```
/table?select=id&column->>baz=cs.{"a=1","b=1"}&column->>baz=not.cs.{"c=1"}
```

but that gives me

```
{
 "code":"42883",
 "details":null,
 "hint":"No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
 "message":"operator does not exist: text @> unknown"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that was one filter too few (looks like that was a logical OR) and one angle bracket too many:

```
/table?select=id&column->baz=cs.{"a=1"}&column->baz=cs.{"b=1"}&column->baz=not.cs.{"c=1"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cs` operator is equivalent to `@>` in PostgreSQL, it will only return true if **all** the elements are contained in the `jsonb` value. You'll need to use the `or` operator for it to work. Also, `cs` should use `[]` instead of `{}`, since we are working with `jsonb` arrays not SQL ones.

```
/table?select=id&or=(column->baz.cs.["a=1"],column->baz.cs.["b=1"])&column->baz=not.cs.["c=1"]
```

The `[]` may need to be percent encoded in order to work:

```
table?select=id&or=(column->baz=cs.%5B"a=1"%5D,column->baz=cs.%5B"b=1"%5D)&column->baz=not.cs.%5B"c=1"%5D
```

As you have noticed, `column->>baz=cs.` didn't work because `->>` returns a `text` value, while `->` returns a `jsonb` one. See the [Postgres JSONB operators page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) for extra info.